# How can I create optimized graphical multicolor logger?

Tags: c++, user-interface, logging, graphics

I am setting up a logger class and want to optimize logging.
It has to be multicolor logger, so std::string::append(...) is not an option.

Adding new log to a vector of strings is not a good idea, because every push_back memory rises and fps goes down. I thought to create `Log` struct that would hold `string msg` and `color` or `flag` that inform us what kind of message is that and double buffer `Log` struct. Write to the first then pass it to the second `Log` object and draw from it, then clear first `Log` object ... and so on. I tried to implement it, but it does not work as I wish, though.

At the moment I left vector of Logs

```
class Logger
{
public:

    struct Log {
        std::string text;
        Uint color;
    }

    void Draw() {
        for(const auto& log : logs) {
            renderer->DrawString(log.text, log.color);
        }
    }


    void AddLog(const std::string& text, Uint color) {
        logs.emplace_back(text, color);
    }

    std::vector<Log> logs;
};


int main() {
    //window stuff, opengl context, etc.
    Logger logger;
    while(!quit) {

        // Do not flood logger with logs, just add it sometimes
        static double lastTime = -1.0;
        if(time - lastTime >= 0.20f) {
            logger.AddLog("Log", 0xff00ffff);
            lastTime = time;
        } 

        logger.Draw();   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

we do not pass position to `renderere->DrawString(...)`, because it gets automatically moved down to another line.

This approach works, but with very, very, very, very, superb poor speed.

How could I optimize it? I would like to get something like cs go console has. It is also a multicolor logger and it can log massive message with no fps drops.

Comment: What is the type of `renderer`?

Comment: Doesn't your problem boil down to just "How do I output colored text?"? Or do you wonder how to represent colored text internally?

Comment: renderer is a class that adds data to the vbo, ebo and somewhere it calls GPU draw call.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I do not want to output text in a "cmd". It meant to be a graphical. I thought I added `GUI` tag but it changed to only ui. I will fix it in a second. Approach reprensented above works, but with poor performance

Comment: The poor speed would come from the function DrawString, the renderer engine wasn't optimized for drawing text. You should do some benchmark to see if the expected behavior can be reached.

Comment: So, follow-up question, does it perform properly when not using multiple colours? Check out [ask], it explaines how you are supposed to reduce your problem to the relevant parts, which you should do before even asking here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Colors do not change anything. You do not understand the question. Read it again, please. Check out https://www.eduplace.com/ss/wtp/testprep/reading.html. The biggest problem was with `std::vector<Log>`, because it is allocating so much memory. I could use `std::string::append(msg)` and that would fix my all problems, because I would have only 1 `std::string`, but color is one per string.

Comment: I think I do understand your question. My point is rather that your question is bad, because it mixes in things that are unrelated to the essence of the problem. The colours are just a distraction and they shouldn't be part of the question!

Comment: The vector *should* be very efficient. It should **not** reallocate memory every time you push_back, probably only once or twice. You can avoid reallocations entirely by using `std::vector::reserve`.

Comment: It may be a problem with how you create `Log` objects, does that involve a lot of work?

Comment: I did not say that memory reallocates every frame, if I did, I did not mean to do that.I meant that it allocates too much memory. Lets take for example vector of strings with vector size = 100 and every string has text = "f". `sizeof(std::vector<std::string>)` =  16, string is `sizeof(100 * sizeof(char)` = 100 so 16 * 100 = 1600. 1600 bytes for the 100 'f' messages - it is worth it? No. It is better to create one `std::string` and append to it 100 times 'f' (with for loop). So sizeof(char) * 100 = 100 bytes instead of 1600. I might calculate something wrong with the size of vector of strings.

Comment: @Galik Log is only a struct with `std::string` and `unsigned int`. Nothing fancy

Comment: Do you know what part is slowing everything down? Is it pushing the `Log` object into the vector or is it something else. Do you also display the log entry? Do you write it to disk?

Comment: Everything what I do is shown above. Only rendering is a magic part of the code, but I have tested it many times and it is not major problem. Every `push_back` call causes that fps drops and memory rises. So pushing/emplacing back is part that slowing everything down. I did also use Performance Profiler and it 
confirms this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid reallocations of your vector when you push log messages to your logger, you can use a ring buffer structure. It preallocates memory for N message and it stores only the latest N messages pushed. A simple implementation can be as follows:

```
template <std::size_t bufferSize>
class Logger {
public:
    struct Data {
        std::string msg = " - ";
        uint32_t color = 0x00000000;
    };

    void addLog(Data && item) {
        buffer_[head_] = std::move(item);
        if (++head_ >= bufferSize) head_ -= bufferSize;
    }

    void draw() const {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i) {
            auto idx = head_ + i;
            if (idx >= bufferSize) idx -= bufferSize;

            // print the log whatever way you like, for example:
            printf("%s\n", buffer_[idx].msg.c_str());
        }    
    }

private:
    std::size_t head_ = 0;
    std::array<Data, bufferSize> buffer_;
};
```

Here, the template parameter `bufferSize` specifies the size of the ring buffer. The `draw()` method processes the oldest messages first, so your newest logs will be at the bottom.

Here is a live example: [link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f0a4f36c797fda2)

Comment: I like this method. Thank you.